# Gtkmm: Using RefPtr with widgets kept in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to keep a `std::vector` of `Gtk::Widget`s that I am showing (and will potentially be) moving around between `Gtk::Container`s.

At the moment I keep a `Gtk::Notebook` which is basically a one-to-one map to the `std::vector`, but if I use `Glib::RefPtr` around the widgets I get problems when removing the widget from the notebook. I already have to use a 'hack' to get a pointer to the underlying Gtk object when adding it to the notebook and I suspect that the Notebook container frees/deletes the object when I remove it from the container.

I have defined my vector of widgets something like this:
`std::vector<Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Widget>> widgets;`

When I add a widget to the vector and the notebook I do:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Widget> w (new Gtk::Widget());
widgets.push_back (w);
Gtk::Widget *wptr = w.operator->(); // hack
notebook.append_page (*wptr);
```

when I try to remove it I do:

```
int c = 1; // widget no. to remove
notebook.remove_page (c);
auto it = widgets.begin() + c;
widgets.erase (it);
```

but this results in a `G_IS_OBJECT` fail assertion when (I think) the element in the `std::vector` is cleaned up at the end of the `iterator` (end of function), since possibly `notebook.remove_page()` already freed the object. How can I do this? Is it possible with `RefPtr`'s?

Related (same assertion failure): [Destructing Glib::RefPtr causes failed assertions in the GTK 3 core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156565/destructing-glibrefptr-causes-failed-assertions-in-the-gtk-3-core)

Comment: In the case of removing the widgets, the vector in the shown example do have at least two widgets? (Remember that the index in a vector is zero-based.)

Comment: Yes. In this example I have assumed that I have added several widgets to the Notebook and the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this because the `Gtk::Notebook` takes ownership of the child objects.  You have to refactor your code to use the `Gtk::Notebook` itself to access the widgets instead of the `vector`, for example with [`Gtk::Notebook::get_nth_page()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Notebook.html#aee6987ef10d8e3afcc40824c53f4c1ad).

Answer (score 3):

Glib::RefPtr<> should not be used with widgets. It is not a general purpose smartpointer. It should only be used with classes that force you to use it - by having no public constructor but having public create*() methods.